# SAPGUI not displaying long_text or text for unhandled custom exceptions

Tags: oop, exception, abap, sap-gui, netweaver

In SAP NetWeaver 7.52 I created an ABAP classed based exception that works fine while executing within a try catch clause in the report/program. But the custom message is not displayed in SAPGUI when the exception is not handled by a try catch clause.

What I'm looking for is that when no try catch is defined the exporting message used at the moment of the raise statements is shown in the "UNCAUGHT_EXCEPTION". I have tried redefining the **get_text( )** and **get_longtext( )** methods. But the ABAP Run time error does not give any useful information to the developer about the cause (which is stored in the "attr_message" attribute of the exception).

When using the "try catch" the message can be retrieved without problems, but the idea is that SAPGUI presents the developer the right message in the "ABAP Runtime Error" report.

**zcx_adk_exception.abap**

```
"! Base exception for all ABAP Development Kit (ADK) exceptions
class zcx_adk_exception definition public create public inheriting from cx_dynamic_check.

    public section.
        "! Initializes the exception message
        "! @parameter message    | Message related to the reason of the exception
        methods constructor
            importing value(message) type zadk_str optional.

        "! Returns the message associated to the exception
        methods get_message
            returning value(result) type zadk_str.

        methods if_message~get_text redefinition.

        methods if_message~get_longtext redefinition.

        private section.
            data attr_message type zadk_str value ''.

endclass.

class zcx_adk_exception implementation.

    method constructor ##ADT_SUPPRESS_GENERATION.
        super->constructor(  ).
        if message is not initial.
            me->attr_message = message.
        endif.
    endmethod.

    method get_message.
        result = me->attr_message.
    endmethod.

    method if_message~get_text.
        result = me->get_message(  ).
    endmethod.

    method if_message~get_longtext.
        result = me->get_message(  ).
    endmethod.

endclass.
```

**What works fine:**

```
try.
    raise exception type zcx_adk_exception exporting message = 'Base_Exception_Error'.
catch zcx_adk_exception into data(ex).
    write: / 'Example 1:', ex->get_message(  ).
    write: / 'Example 2:', ex->get_text(  ).
    write: / 'Example 2:', ex->get_longtext(  ).
endtry.
```

And the output is this:

[image]

**What does not work:**

```
" Not Catching the exception
raise exception type zcx_adk_exception exporting message = 'Base_Exception_Error'.
```

This results in the following message being displayed instead

[image]

Comment: You might simplify your question a lot by using a 2-lines exception class and complete it with the calling method so that to make it a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Moreover the title doesn't reflect the issue that is you can't handle the exception.

Comment: Well the behaviour you described is a normal behaviour of SAP. Any uncaught exception will result in a short dump, there is nothing you can do about it. If you want to catch everything then you could CATCH cx_root in the TRY CATCH clause in the outermost part of your program. Note that this will not work with exceptions that inherit from CX_DYNAMIC_CHECK as they have to be declared in each method they want to be propagated from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the previously proposed idea of using a message I came up with the following code that allows the exception to be raised with a message. This allows the exception to show the right message when called within a "try catch" block and display a useful message in the "Error analysis" section of the dump generated by SAPGUI.

**Solution:**

```
"! Program to test functionalities and utilities
REPORT zsandbox_tests.


" Exception Class
CLASS lcl_exception DEFINITION INHERITING FROM cx_dynamic_check.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    INTERFACES if_t100_dyn_msg.
    METHODS if_message~get_text REDEFINITION.
    METHODS constructor
      IMPORTING VALUE(message) TYPE string.

  PRIVATE SECTION.
    DATA attr_message TYPE string VALUE ''.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_exception IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD if_message~get_text.
    result = attr_message.
  ENDMETHOD.

  METHOD constructor.
    super->constructor(  ).
    me->attr_message = message.
  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.



" Class that raises the exception
CLASS lcl_main DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    CLASS-METHODS main RAISING lcl_exception.
ENDCLASS.
CLASS lcl_main IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD main.
    DATA raise_message TYPE string VALUE 'Custom Message for the Exception'.
    RAISE EXCEPTION TYPE lcl_exception
        MESSAGE e000(lcl_exception) WITH raise_message '' '' '' " The if_t100_dyn_msg supports 4 attributes: V1, V2, V3 and V4 but I only use the first one
        EXPORTING message = raise_message.

  ENDMETHOD.
ENDCLASS.


" Call to Main Method
START-OF-SELECTION.

  TRY.
      lcl_main=>main( ).
    CATCH lcl_exception INTO DATA(ex).
      WRITE ex->get_text(  ).
  ENDTRY.
```

This generates the following output:
[image: Output of try catch]

**When no try catch is used:**

```
" Call to Main Method
start-of-selection.
  lcl_main=>main( ).
```

This is the output:
[image: SAPGUI dump]

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR : SAP did not plan to permit the customization of a short dump by the developer.

A "short dump" is a report which is generated by the ABAP kernel when an unexpected error occurs in an ABAP program, i.e. an error due to a bug in the program (usually an uncaught exception, or non-catchable errors) or to a system failure (input/output resources, memory resources, etc.)

It's intended to help the developer analyze the cause of the error and correct it.

It's not intended to be generated on purpose, except in a situation that the developer has made theoretically impossible, but actually happens, and which is thought to require many information to analyze if it happens, hence a short dump.

If it's really your intention to generate a short dump with a message, for some purpose, there are two ways:

- [`MESSAGE 'message text' TYPE 'X'.`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenabap_messages_types.htm) (often used in standard SAP programs, especially in update function modules)
- [`RAISE SHORTDUMP ...`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapraise_shortdump.htm) or `... THEN THROW SHORTDUMP ...` in conditional expression. Both exist since ABAP 7.53. For instance `RAISE SHORTDUMP TYPE zcx_adk_exception EXPORTING message = 'Base_Exception_Error'.`

The short dump will contain the message text in the Analysis section.

Comment: Your idea of using messages was exactly what I needed. I found that is possible to use messages while raising an exception, and I have created an answer with a short example to demonstrate it